# Do I need to pay tax if I earned 10 pounds interest from peer-to-peer investment?

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, investing, interest

If I earned 10 pounds in tax year 2014/15, do I need to pay tax?

I just started investing in Funding Circle, I earned few pounds. This just looks silly to pay tax from 10 pounds but maybe that doesn't matter, and I need to pay tax from every pound? I'm also employed full time.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your whole situation (not just the fact that you have only £10 from p2p investments). ie. if you have to so a self assessment then yes you have to declare the additional £10 from p2p

In order to decide if you have to do a self assessment there is a question list on the HMRC web site

https://www.gov.uk/check-if-you-need-a-tax-return

Hope this helps